# How can I initialise all DOM elements that share a class and store them in an object?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Say I have a list of elements that share a class, and I want to extract the innerText from these elements and store them as properties of an object. Currently I'm manually initialising them using getElementById('').innerText etc.

Is there a way to iterate through all elements of a certain class and automatically store the results as object properties? How would I write this function?

```
<div>
  <p class="queue" id="para1">42</p>
  <p class="queue" id="para2">23</p>
  <p class="queue" id="para3">78</p>
</div>
```

```
let obj = {
  var1: 42,
  var2: 23,
  var3: 78
}
```

The above is the result i'm looking for, or similar.

Comment: "Currently I'm manually initialising them using getElementById('').innerText etc." Please edit your question to include the code you've written so far.

Comment: Sorry @JordanRunning, this was something I was working on earlier today and the idea of asking SE only came to me just now. I'll edit it when I get access to the code again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select all the Elements into an Array like structure (a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)), and then use [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop over while forming the Object

```js
let obj = {};

document.querySelectorAll('.queue').forEach((ele, i) => {
  obj['var' + (i + 1)] = ele.textContent;
});

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="queue" id="para1">42</p>
  <p class="queue" id="para2">23</p>
  <p class="queue" id="para3">78</p>
</div>
```